# UI Difference iOS7 iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ios7, xcode5

Please have a look at screenshots:

- 1: From iOS Store, (Same application code, before iOS7)
- 2: Compiled
  from xCode5, (Same application code.)

[image: From iOS Store, (Same application code, before iOS7)]

[image: Compiled from xCode5, (Same application code.)]

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this difference? Why the appstore app shows old glossy finish and app build from xcode 5 dont?

Anyway to get back to old glossy finish UI from xcode?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> This happens because your app on appStore was compiled in iOS 6 SDK,
>   So Navigation bar, TabBar and other default UI elements were looking
>   like iOS 6. When you compile same code in xCode 5 Default UI Elements
>   will look like iOS 7, Because xCode 5 has iOS 7 SDK.

If you run your app in iOS 6 simulator or iOS 6 Device you will get that old UI. But if you are running your app in iOS 7 device or iOS 7 simulator new UI will be applied.

To get back to old UI you have to use xCode 4.6 or you have to make custom UI elements instead of using default UI elements.

But if you are using xCode 4.6 and not supporting iOS 7 then apple may reject your app.

**Conclusion: You must use custom UI elements to get old style UI. OR in iOS 7 it will look like simple and flat as iOS 7 design.**

Answer (score 2):

You can **not** set the style back. The old style is not accessible anymore in iOS 7. You need to change the given *system theme* so it looks like the old one.

You can set an background image for the `UINavigationBar`. The image has to look like the black rectangle with the glossy white

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"controllerBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The same for the `UISearchBar`

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBackground.png"];
```

Or `UITabBar`

```
tabBar backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarBackground.png"]];
```

Comment: Same principle, you could even change every button to a custom one with its own background in the tabBar since they've gotten flat too.

Answer (score 0):

In xCode 4.5 iPhone architecture is differ from the old xCode Version. So Your App Store build made using old xCode version. So it will looks like iOS6 UI..

When you make build from new xCode4.5 than iOS7 new architecture will be applied and it will inherits all new UI features ..